# Hazelcast map value serialization exception

Tags: java, hazelcast

I tried to put my entity object to Hazelcast IMap but it throws an exception like below:

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException
```

I've searched Google but could not find an exact answer.

Answer (score 4):

Then I tried to serialize my nested entity objects with

```
implements Serializable
```

then now I can set the value to the IMap and can get the object as same as I set. So if you see something like that you have to implement your object with Serializable interface.

Comment: Any reason why I would be getting this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554502/getting-classnotfoundexception-when-accessing-object-across-cluster

Answer (score 1):

Any object (and the ones nested in it) should be marked as serializable. It is also worth noting that your option is not just limited to `Serializable`.

You can also make use of other serialization interfaces supported by hazelcast, viz. `DataSerializable`, `IdentifiedDataSerializable` among others which performs much better than `Serializable`.

Please find below a comparison table which may help you to decide which one to use.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/serializationcomparisontable.html#comparison-table